# Two definitions of an overloaded method called printArray

Tags: java, arrays

Here is the problem and what I have, but I know it's wrong because there's no newline or carriage return.

Problem: Write 2 definitions of an overloaded method called printArray. One method should accept a reference to a one dimensional array of integers as a parameter and should print the elements of the array on a single line separated by spaces and followed by a "newline" or "carriage return."

The second method definition should accept a reference to a two-dimensional array of integers and two primitive integers called numberOfRows and numberOfColumns as parameters and should print the elements of the two dimensional array as a table.

```
    public static void printArray(int[]s) {
       for (int i = 0; i<s.length; i++) {
           System.out.println(s[i]);
       }
    }

    public static void printArray(int[][]table, int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns) {
       for (int row = 0; row <numberOfRows; row++)
          for (int col = 0; col <numberOfColumns; col++)
             table[row][col]=input.nextInt();    
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Won't fully solve it for you, but here's a hint:
`System.out.print()` outputs the content as-is without introducing a linebreak, `System.out.println()` will output the content (if any), and output a linebreak afterwards

Answer (score 0):

why dont you code as following:

```
public static void printArray(int[][]table)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: because there is no newline or carriage return and apparently I have to have one of those.

Comment: @erin3elizabeth as I said in the comment to your question, newline & carriage return is equivalent to a linebreak, so println actually implicates that.

Comment: @erin3elizabeth ye this is the second method. 1st you have already did fine.